# Double tag badge

Tags: bug, status-declined, badges

It looks like one user was awarded the silver [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) badge [twice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/79/code-golf?userid=78850) at the same time.

[image]

Their [badges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal?tab=badges) page also shows the badge being awarded twice:

[image]

This looks like a bug. It could be that Lyxal messed something up by [traveling in time](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57219749#57219749) to get it twice, but if it's happened to others, it may need to be fixed. On the other hand, this looks a benign bug, and it's not really hurting anyone.

<sub>Sorry, Lyxal. [Blame ChartZ Belatedly](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57413559#57413559), not me.</sub>

Comment: This is heresy. Delete this immediately. :p

Comment: This looks like a minor issue that isn't impacting how things are working which is why we status-declined this. However, if there are more instances of users being awarded the same badge twice please let us know and we may revisit if this is a larger bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On the other hand, this looks a benign bug, and it's not really hurting anyone.

## Exactly

Why go and fix something that only happened to one user when no one else is being bothered by the issue?

But on a more serious note, it is such a small problem that realistically, StackExchange probably isn't going to fix. If it was happening to multitudes of people, then maybe a fix might be needed, but that isn't the case here.

Nothing wrong with a bit of fun here and there. I find it a fitting testimony to my ability to break things accidentally.

Comment: On the other hand: leaving this bug report open means that if SE ever bothers to do some bug fixing, we have *something* to show them, however insignificant it may be (no, I totally don't want to rob you of an extra badge ;P)

Comment: @ChartZBelatedly that's making a big assumption that SE will change to actually care about their sub-sites.